# Analytical solution of a polynomial $a\cdot x^{e}+b\cdot x^{4\cdot e}+c =0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Is it possible to get an analytical solution of the equation

$a\cdot x^{2\cdot e}+b\cdot x^{e+1}+c =0$

Which can be also written as (due to the value of $e$):

$a\cdot x^{e}+b\cdot x^{4\cdot e}+c =0$

where $a,b,c$ and $e$ are constants? of course, without the $+1$ in the $e+1$, a simple change of variable can do the trick.

Comment: After substituting $u=x^e$ you can apply the quartic formula, or you can use the reduction techniques that are used to derive it. The result is horrible, though.

Comment: @Ian , thanks that works, but I guess that result is not avoidable if one wants an analytic solution. I see that you answered my question, so please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After substituting $u=x^e$ you can apply the quartic formula, or you can use the reduction techniques that are used to derive it. The result is horrible, though.